# Assistance with coding change in Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which unzip and renames each file.
Unfortunately I now need to keep the filename of the zip file it came from.

Example Jazz1.zip now unzips and the outcoming text file becomes `1.Jazz1.zip.txt`.
So I want `%%F` to become `%%F - 4`- characters.

Unfortunately I want it to be `Jazz1.txt`.

```
::Setup the stage...
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET folder=C:\P\DataSource2_W
SET count=1

::Action
CD "%folder%"
FOR %%F IN ("*.zip") DO (

 "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\wzunzip" %%F
  MOVE *.txt "C:\P\DataSource2_W\TextFiles\!count!%%F.txt"
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand what you are trying to do with the COUNT variable, nor do I understand how you are handling a ZIP file with multiple .TXT files.

But I do understand that you want the base name of each ZIP file, (name without the extension). That is easy - simply use the ~n modifier (type `HELP FOR` from the command prompt for more info).

So if `%%F` = `Jazz1.zip`, then `%%~nF` yields `Jazz1`